# Problem in pinch zoom of an image

Tags: android

i m developing an application for zooming an image by pinch. I am done with the code but can we check that the application is running successful in emulator...? kindly reply.

Comment: you should google your question first before asking on SO. There are lot of tutorial on pinch zoom on andoid.

Comment: @Sujit the poster is not asking how to do pinch/zoom, he is asking how to emulate multiple fingers with the emulator- a good question, in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Pinch/ zoom is not supported on the eclipse emulator due to it being a multitouch. any simple gesture that is not multitouch can be tested.

You have to use a real device to test multitouch....

hope this helps

Chris